# Programmatically configure MS Activesync in iPhone

Tags: iphone, activesync

I want to know if I can programmatically configure MS ActiveSync, I want to push parameters from server.

Regards
Jeet

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveSync protocol supports [auto-discovery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc539114.aspx) of configuration parameters to minimize the amount of configuration work required by the device owner to connect to their email account. The iPhone already supports auto-discovery ([PDF](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/How_To_Setup_Guide.pdf)), so that might meet your needs (assuming your email server). If you'd like to test if your email service is configured for auto-discovery, you can use [this tool](http://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/).

I'm not sure if you can programmatically configure ActiveSync, though. I doubt it's possible without either a lot of effort or hacking around. You can certainly create a configuration profile for your accounts which will make setup a breeze, and that's typically how it's done ([PDF](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_Device_Configuration_Overview.pdf)) within large enterprises anyway.